# Giving a JPanel priority focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel, keylistener

I have a JPanel that is using a KeyListener as the content pane as the window; however, there are buttons and text fields in a grid layout on top of the JPanel.

How do I prioritize the focus of the JPanel that it retains focus after editing text or clicking the buttons so I can read the key input?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `FocusListener` on the `focusLost` event and then request focus back again. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JPanelFocus {
  public static void main(String... argv) throws Exception {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("FocusTest");
        JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        final JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(b);
        // Here is the KeyListener installed on our JPanel
        p.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
            System.out.println(ev.getKeyChar());
          }
        });
        // This is the bit that does the magic - make sure
        // that our JPanel is always focussed
        p.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
          public void focusLost(FocusEvent ev) {
            p.requestFocus();
          }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        // Make sure JPanel starts with the focus
        p.requestFocus();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This won't work if you have fields that need to keep the focus though (you mentioned an editable text field). When should key events go to the text field and when should they go to the JPanel?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could also just make the child components non-focusable.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    public MyPanel() {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        // for each component
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addItem("Item1");
        this.add(comboBox);
        // this is what keeps each child from intercepting KeyEvents
        comboBox.setFocusable(false);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { ... }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { ... }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // add MyPanel to frame
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```